# what is the Use of Super() in child class even we are not passing any argument

Tags: python, super

```py
    class Base(object):
        def __init__(self):
           self.fname="MS"
           self.lname="Dhoni"
    
    class Child(Base):
       def __init__(self):
           self.fname="kohli"
           super(Base).__init__()
```

What is use of super method in above code even commenting the `super(Base).__init__()` I am getting output `kohli`
please explain

Comment: It calls the `__init__()` method of `object`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Python super() with \_\_init\_\_() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `super(Base)` which means the **parent** of `Base` class who is `object` class, so you're **not** calling the `Base.__init__` method, which means **no** re-assignment of `fname` which stays to `kohli`

---

What you want is parent of `Child` class, with current instance `self`

```
super(Child, self).__init__()
```

But in fact you can just do the following, that's the same

```
super().__init__()
```

Comment: but why i am getting output kohli that should be MS ?please explain what would be the output in both case when "super keyword" is commented and uncommented ?

Comment: @Wanted123 please read again the first paragraph of my answer ;)